# Find the maximum possible number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[image]

I've tried to rewrite each number descriptively and I turn out to:

[image]

But I do think I'm missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Let $x=\overline{bcd}$ then
$$1000a+x=(a+1)x+100a+56\implies x=900-\frac{56}{a}\in\mathbb{N}.$$
Hence the digit $a$ divides $56=2^3\cdot 7$. Since here we are looking for the maximum, we should try first with the case $a=8$.

Comment: Great! Thanks! I assumed that the common part `bcd` must be used in some way...